# How to connect Java test project with ADO Test Plans

Tags: azure-devops, ado

We have Java project with cucumber tests we are trying to migrate over to ADO Test plans.

[this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops) talks about how to do it from Visual studio however Visual studio no longer supports Java, se are trying to do it from vsCode instead. After installing all the required extensions the 'Test Explorer' is not picking the BDD scenarios. Instead, it is showing only the main runner Java package. Any idea ?

Comment: The Java Test Runner do not support showing BDD scenarios in the test explorer. Now all the test item discovery are annotation based. Please file a feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test if you want to have cucumber support. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @ShengChen. Assuming we use that extension with annotations is there an article available to demonstrate how a test can be linked with test plans ?

Comment: Sorry, it does not support linking test items to the test plan/features now. The extension discovery the tests which have some specific annotations. Like `@Test`, `@Testable`, ...

Comment: Thanks again @ShengChen . So is my assumption that linking test items to the test plan/features is only supported with Visual studio means you can't write your tests in Java correct ? And if we use Annotations can those be linked back to test cases in test plans via those annotations or only back to "normal" work items such as User story ?

Comment: AFAIK, VS Code Java Test Runner extension does not have any support/integration with the Azure DevOps now.

Comment: So only Visual studio meaning you can't use Java. Well that's just great :)